# Check whether a Lilypond (.ly) file is valid with python

Tags: python, validation, file, lilypond

Do you know a pythonic simple way to check whether a Lilypond (.ly) file is valid ?

Comment: A quick google search gave me this [Lilypond parser in Python](http://code.google.com/p/lilykde/source/browse/trunk/frescobaldi/python/ly/tokenize.py). Did you search or did you come right over here?-)

Answer (score 2):

For a complex lilypond file, there's no simple way in Python to check that it's well formed.  The main reason is that a lilypond file is no simple data file, but is actually a set of Scheme code/macros, so any Python parser would have to embed an entire Scheme parser to check for macros, type check that the input to macros is of the correct type, etc.  This is the main reason why my project (music21) has never implemented a lilypond parser, even though it will make Lilypond output.  The Frescobaldi module can parse some lilypond.  The best pure-Python toolkit for parsing (and generating) complete Lilypond is [Abjad](http://packages.python.org/Abjad/); it too is not simple to use, but it is very powerful.